# Is there alternatives proofs that if $m^4 + 4^n$ is prime number then $m$ is odd and $n $ is even?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, alternative-proof

> Show that if $m^4 + 4^n$ is prime, $m>0$, $n>0$, then $m$ is odd and $n$ is even, except when $m=n=1$.

This question has an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52837/if-m44n-is-prime-then-m-n-1-or-m-is-odd-and-n-even) but I am asking for alternative proof(s). **All of these duplicates have the same factorisation (the same solution )**

My attempt: it is clear that $m$ should be odd , any number can be written in one of these forms:   $5k+1 , \  5k+2 , \ 5k-2, \ 5k-1 ,  \ 5k  $, for odd numbers in the form  of $5k \pm 2$  note that $4^n \mod 10 =4 $ for all odd numbers. Let $4^n= 4+ 10 q$
$$(m)^4 + 4^n = 5(125 k^4 \pm 8\cdot  25 k^3 + 24\cdot 5 k^2 \pm 8k )+ 16 + 4 + 5 \cdot 2 \cdot q $$

It is clear that this is always a multiple of $5$.

The same approach will work for $5k \pm 1 $.

I couldn't find a way to prove this for multiples of $5$ i.e $ 5k$.

Comment: Could you elaborate why [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/52838/1203597) isn't enough?

Comment: @SohamSaha I don't know what "Sophie Germain Identity"  is. This question is an exercise  in the first chapter of my number theory book  so I need an "elementary proof".

Comment: I believe that [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52837/if-m44n-is-prime-then-m-n-1-or-m-is-odd-and-n-even#comment119366_52838) comment can sort that out. Sophie Germain Identity is nothing but [a factorization for $a^4+4b^4$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie_Germain#Honors_in_number_theory:~:text=Sophie%20Germain%27s%20identity%20states%20that%20for%20any%20%7Bx%2C%20y%7D)

Comment: Do you consider your question resolved?

Comment: @SohamSaha well, am curious to see if there are some other ways than this.

Comment: The fourth powers modulo $5$ are $0^4\equiv 0$, $(\pm 1)^4\equiv 1$ and $(\pm 2)^4 \equiv 1$ (because $2^4=16$). Working in this way simplifies what you have done for the non-zero residues considerably.